# Why does my marginated tortoise have a soft shell?

Tags: health, diet, tortoises

My 1 <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub> year old marginated tortoise still has a soft shell. Also he hasn't grown much since I got him, he is still 4 cm long. I'm pretty sure I'm giving him the correct nutrition because I've researched really well. As for lighting, I live in Greece so this is the lighting he would get in the wild. Any tips?

Here is a picture of his enclosure:

[image]

Comment: What sort of nutrition is he getting? These sorts of details will help us help you help your tortoise. :)

Comment: is it outdoors in the sun or inside the house getting sunlight from a window,do you add vitamins and minerals to the food,please give more information.

Comment: I keep him outside in my balcony. He has many humid hiding areas to hide in as well. I generally feed him leaves from my plants and maybe a flower like an orchid once in a while. I haven't been giving him any vitamins or minerals either.